# Where to store angular templates in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm using angular.js as my clientside framework and rails as my serverside framework. One slight stumbling block is where should I store my *angular* view templates?

Let's say I'm making a custom directive:

```
directive("foobaz", function (cart) { return {
    restrict: "E",
    templateUrl: "components/bing/foobaz.html"
}
```

How should I serve up `components/bing/foobaz.html`? Should I put it in my public folder:

```
root/public/bing/foobaz.html
```

Or should I make routes and a controller to serve up angular views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a folder app/assets/templates/.

It will hold all of your angular templates. please refer this link to get more details http://start.jcolemorrison.com/setting-up-an-angularjs-and-rails-4-1-project/

Answer (score 1):

you can use layouts folder in

app -> views -> layouts

or 
 with .yml, we can store it in config and no need to mention in routes.

Answer (score 0):

We have angular-rails application.
And we store templates in app/assets/templates dir, and use haml for templates. For those purposes we're using [angular-rails-templates gem](https://github.com/pitr/angular-rails-templates)